# Prove by induction. Graph, Equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, induction, tiling

Take an equilateral triangle with side length $2^n$. Divide it up into equilateral triangles with side length 1, and delete the top triangle. Call this shape $T_n$:

[image]

Take three of the smaller equaliteral triangles, and join them together to form the following shape:

[image: Formed shape]

Prove that you can tile $T_n$ with tiles of this shape for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

I prove for the base case but I don't know how to continue with inductive steps. Want some way of 'relating' $T_{n+1}$ and $T_n$; that is, some way of turning the task "cover an equilateral triangle with side length $2^{n+1}$ with our tiles" into the task "cover an equilateral triangle with side length $2^n$ with our tiles."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to the *intended* question:

[image]

$T_1$ is just one of our small three-triangle tiles; $T_n$ can be formed from four copies of $T_{n-1}$ and one more small tile as shown above, so can be tiled entirely with small tiles. The arrangement of the small tiles is reminiscent of the chair substitution.

Comment: Thank you for the editing!
I'm so sorry there was a huge typo which impacts the correct answer.
The equilateral triangle with side length "_2n_" should be _2^n_.
And I am still confused on how to prove _Tn⇒Tn+1_.